# Flash AS3 extract numbers from String (regexp?)

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3

I am sending a var to Flash:

```
// incoming
var pageColor:String = "rgb(81, 89, 112)";
```

I have this function to covert the RGB values to a HEX

```
function rgb2hex(r:Number, g:Number, b:Number) {
    return '0x'+(r << 16 | g << 8 | b).toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
// trace(rgb2hex(81, 89, 112));
```

Now I am looking for the best way to extract the numbers from the `pageColor` string and use them in the `rgb2hex` function..

Comment: Regex is a good solution... have you tried?

Comment: No, I really need to learn it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pageColor = pageColor.substring(4, pageColor.length - 1); // '81, 89, 112'
var colors:Array = pageColor.split(",");
rgb2hex(parseInt(colors[0]), parseInt(colors[1]), parseInt(colors[2]));
```

As an aside, you should change the arguments to your `rbg2hex` function to take `int` or `uint` instead of number.

Comment: Thanks Cory, the only thing I needed to change for AS3 compatibility was:

var colors:Array = pageColor.split(",");

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageColor:String = "rgb(81, 89, 112)";

pageColor = pageColor.substring(4, pageColor.length - 1);
var colors:Array = pageColor.split(",");

function rgb2hex(r:int, g:int, b:int) {
    return '0x'+(r << 16 | g << 8 | b).toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
trace(rgb2hex(parseInt(colors[0]), parseInt(colors[1]), parseInt(colors[2])));
```